# Way to revoke the signed URL created in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, signed-url

I have a signed URL
`$gsutil signurl -d 7m <private-key> gs: //<bucket>\<obj>` is there any way to revoke access of a signed URL without deleting the service account.
I have seen some questions but couldn't find anything without deleting the service account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signed URL can only be revoked by invalidating the service account public key.